# spring data mongodb mapping dynamic field same field

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have this model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "dyn_fields")
public class Field<T extends Object> extends AuditModel implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6630923680212053917L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private ObjectId companyId;
    private T value; 
    private String label;
    private LocalDate validationDate;
    
    public Field(T value) {
        
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    
}
```

the Value field can be of any type: String, Integer, Double and c ...

the insertion in the mongodb database works correctly as shown in the image:
[image]

how can I do a mapping of my records not knowing the type of the value field?
I'm currently casting all fields, I don't think that's the correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof` to evaluate the type of the property.
example

```
if(value instanceof String) {
// String mapping logic
} 
if(value instanceof Integer) {
// Integer mapping logic
}
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing right now. I wanted to understand if there is a better solution